# WPF DataSet/Query Designer VS2010

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dataset-designer

Is there any good Dataset designer control similar to "Crystal Reports Database Expert", which I can provide in my application. All I need to do show tables and Let the users establish relationships between those tables and select fields to view. As this data comes from different sources, and the number of columns changes a lot, I can populate tables in the dataset, and the users need to establish relations. Selected fields will be be displayed the built query against the dataset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it interesting that the Query Components from the Microsoft Report Builder can be used in your application very easily. However, they are not documented at all.. and interestingly, the report builder is a redistributable, so I assume that to redistribute, these components with your application you need to package the entire report builder too.
Another catch is that, Report Builder 3 is not compatible with VS 2010 report viewer, the Query builder is crappy, so you have to use Report 2.0. Also the components are x86 builds, so just keep an eye on it :)

This is the option I used in my app.. and I was able manage it to work... and the good thing is that this is better than the third party components I looked at.